# Deleted commit still visible from GitLab web interface, exposing sensitive data

Tags: git

Some weeks ago I accidentally committed a configuration file containing some passwords and I pushed it on a GitLab remote managed by my company.

After that I used [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to remove the passwords from the history.

After the clean I executed:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
git push --force
```

I seen the commit hashes have been changed and sensitive data has been removed (I can see that both using the GitLab web interface or exploring a new clone of the repo).

However, if I access one of the old pages calling directly the URL (`https://<my-company>/gitlab/test-bfg/commit/<theoretically-unexisting-hash>`) I can see a gitdiff of a commit containing the passwords! I discovered this accidentally, navigating on the browser history.

If I try to checkout the same hash on the just cloned repo I obtain this message:

```
fatal: reference is not a tree: d7fb999c...
```

So, if a person clone that repo from GitLab I *think* he or she is not able to view that commit*, however it is still visible from the web interface, if one could guess an old hash.
** Anyway, I I would feel more comfortable reading `did not match any file(s) known to git` instead of `reference is not a tree`.*

I don't think this is a kind of cache problem, because I tried it again after some hours.

So, questions are:

- Why this happens? Am I using the tools in the wrong way?
- There are some ways to see that hidden hashes?
- Did you ever experienced this, maybe using different systems (GitHub, BitBucket)?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git gc` only affects your local copy and the following `git push` will not propagate any instruction for garbage collection to the remote site. See also [How can I trigger garbage collection on a Git remote repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162786/how-can-i-trigger-garbage-collection-on-a-git-remote-repository) and [Removing sensitive data from a repository (at github)](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/). And while the last one helps you with removing some sensitive data it also contains a clear warning of the limitations of this approach:

> Warning: **Once you have pushed a commit to GitHub, you should consider any data it contains to be compromised.**
>   ... commits may **still be accessible in any clones or forks** of your
>   repository, **directly via their SHA-1 hashes in cached views** on GitHub,
>   and through any pull requests that reference them. You can't do
>   anything about existing clones or forks of your repository, but you
>   can permanently remove all of your repository's cached views and pull
>   requests on GitHub by contacting GitHub Support.

And while this is from Github it is probably similar on Gitlab.

Comment: I think it could be the same cached views issue you pointed out. I asked also in GitLab forum. I'll update my question if they will answer me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not very familiar with Gitlab or what BFG repo cleaner does. But it is always a good idea to rotate your passwords when they have been exposed in public. If it's a public repository, there's no way to reliably know if the old git commits have been checked out by someone. That said, lodge a support request with GitLab too, just in case.

Comment: Yes, these is a good advice. However the repo is currently private and I wanted to remove the passwords just because we decided to make it public soon. I hoped simply rewriting the history could be enough. Anyway, I asked also in GitLab forum. I'll update my question if they will answer me.